# Update record in CRM 2015 using HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I need to update a record in CRM 2015 using web api in C#. However when processing, I got this error "Method not allowed" Status Code 405.

Here is some sample code.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain") });
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json");

HttpRequestMessage retrieveReq = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceUrl + "SalesOrderSet(guid'" + orderId + "')");
retrieveReq.Headers.Accept.Clear();
retrieveReq.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
retrieveReq.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-us"));
retrieveReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json");
retrieveReq.Headers.Add("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
retrieveReq.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
retrieveReq.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
retrieveReq.Headers.Host = server_name;
retrieveReq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength.ToString(), "117");
retrieveReq.Headers.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
retrieveReq.Headers.Pragma.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("no-cache"));

var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "value"));
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
retrieveReq.Content = content;

await client.SendAsync(retrieveReq).ContinueWith(
                     (postTask) =>
                     {
                         postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                     });
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Error 405 usually means you are trying to send a method different than the expected by the server (normally the HttpVerb is wrong). You are using POST so could you try with GET? HttpMessage.Get.

**Edit**: looks like update operations require a PATCH verb. Others will require a PUT, and deletions must use DELETE.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607664.aspx

Comment: Yes, i tried with Get method, it's working. the problem is with the POST method, I need to update the CRM using the api.

Comment: 405 means HttpVerb is wrong. Just edited the original answer :)